# powerline jason messed up after trying to restart using "powerline-daemon --replace"

Tags: json, bash, powerline

1. I tried installing powerline for bash linux. It was working fine with all the changes for git etc..
2. By mistake I typed powerline-daemon --replace and from then I started getting this error,

`Expecting ',' delimiter: line 13 column 6 (char 147).`

Any clue what could be the issue. I did check all the json files for the , delimiters, wherever I added the git related codes but unable to find any the reason. I tried doing the below command but the results are same.

```
powerline-daemon k and then powerline-damen q
```

Any help/suggestion would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Got it resolved.

1. Missed , while adding new segments.
2. Also used // for comments and looks like its not possible in the json.